# jQuery previous slide hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-cycle

I have my script set up so that when the user clicks on the previous link it will display the previous slide, however, I have set it up so that when the user hovers over the next and previous buttons a small portion of the next/prev slide is bounced in to view and then hidden again when the mouse is moved off these buttons.

However, the previous slide does not come in to view...how can I get this to work?

I have created a jsfiddle of my script - http://jsfiddle.net/BHbGY/1/

Comment: It works fine for me in Firefox 10...

Comment: I need the blue one to appear when you hover over the previous link on the red slide - the black is the background

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that...Thought it was the slide

Comment: No unfortunately, I don't know how to make it cycle so when you hover it looks like it's looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a working example of everything below](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/8emM8/16/).

My approach would be to first simplify the html:

```
<div id="slide_nav">
   <a href="#" class="prev">&laquo; Previous</a>
   <a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
</div>
<ul id="slide_container">
   <li class="one slide">one</li>
   <li class="two slide focused">two</li>
   <li class="three slide">three</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of using all the fixed widths (e.g. `width: 9999px;`) I'd set all the li attributes to a width of 100% and use position of absolute. Then you may simply change the `left` attribute to move things around.

```
#slide_container li {
   width: 100%;
   height: 600px;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

#slide_container .one {
   background-color: #900;
   left: -100%;    
}

#slide_container .two {
   display: block;
   background-color: #090;
}

#slide_container .three {
   background-color: #009;
   left: 100%;   
}
```

This might seem tricky at first since `animate` doesn't like percentages much. But your elements will automagically fill their container, so it's worth this extra little conversion on page load to make it all work:

```
    // change all percentages to pixels because animate hates percent
    // and seems to lose position over time
    var base = 0-$('#slide_container li').eq(0).outerWidth(true);
    $('#slide_container li').each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.css('left', base+'px');
       base += $this.outerWidth(true);
    });
```

Then create a plugin, which will simplify your code structure:

```
$.fn.extend({
    slideMyDivs: function(method, amount) {
        if (!amount) {
            amount = this.eq(0).outerWidth(true);
        }
        switch (method) {
        case 'prev':
            this.stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '+=' + amount
            }, {
                duration: 600,
                easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
            });
            break;
        case 'next':
            this.stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '-=' + amount
            }, {
                duration: 600,
                easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
            });
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid method: ' + method);
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Then I would set up a method to disable the links when you reach end/start of the list:

```
function toggleLinks() {
    if (!hasPrev()) {
        $('#slide_nav .prev')
            .addClass('disabled')
            .bind('click.disabled', function() { return false; });
    }
    else {
        $('#slide_nav .prev').removeClass('disabled').unbind('.disabled');
    }

    if (!hasNext()) {
        $('#slide_nav .next').addClass('disabled').bind('click.disabled', function() {
            return false;
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#slide_nav .next').removeClass('disabled').unbind('.disabled');
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you want it to cycle back (which is a bit beyond the scope of this question), you could move the last element to the beginning by setting it's `left` css attribute with something like this:

```
function send_to_start($elm) {
   var newPos = $('#slide_container li').eq(0).pos().left - $elm.outerWidth(true);
   $elm.css('left', newPos+'px');
}
```

Then I'd set up the events like so:

```
$('#slide_nav a').mouseenter(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var p = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? 'prev' : 'next';
        showPreview(p);
    }
}).mouseleave(function() {
    cancelPreview($(this).hasClass('prev') ? 'prev' : 'next');
});

$('#slide_nav .prev').click(function() {
    cancelPreview('prev');
    if (hasPrev()) {
        $('#slide_container li').slideMyDivs('prev').filter('.focused').removeClass('focused').prev().addClass('focused');
        toggleLinks();
    }
    return false;
});

$('#slide_nav .next').click(function() {
    cancelPreview('next');
    if (hasNext()) {
        $('#slide_container li').slideMyDivs('next').filter('.focused').removeClass('focused').next().addClass('focused');
        toggleLinks();
    }
    return false;
});
```

And here are the misc functions called by those event handlers:

```
function showPreview(method) {
    var p = method == 'prev',
        $n = p ? $('#slide_container li.focused').prev() : $('#slide_container li.focused').next();
    $n.addClass('previewActive')
        .slideMyDivs((p ? 'prev' : 'next'), '75');
}

function cancelPreview(method) {
    var p = method == 'prev';
    $('#slide_container li.previewActive')
        .removeClass('previewActive')
        .slideMyDivs((p ? 'next' : 'prev'), '75');
}

function hasPrev() {
    return $('#slide_container .focused').prev().length > 0;
}

function hasNext() {
    return $('#slide_container .focused').next().length > 0;
}

function toggleLinks() {
    if (!hasPrev()) {
        $('#slide_nav .prev')
            .addClass('disabled')
            .bind('click.disabled', function() { return false; });
    }
    else {
        $('#slide_nav .prev').removeClass('disabled').unbind('.disabled');
    }

    if (!hasNext()) {
        $('#slide_nav .next').addClass('disabled').bind('click.disabled', function() {
            return false;
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#slide_nav .next').removeClass('disabled').unbind('.disabled');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

You just had your margins off as well as 'slide_container li' in next and 'slide_container' in prev for the hovers.

http://jsfiddle.net/BHbGY/3/